# How to read file to array bytes from gridfs?

Tags: mongodb, scala, gridfs, reactivemongo

I want to get Array/List[Byte] from Enumerator[Array[Byte]]. Some articles show me how to do it in playframework. But I'm not using play framework for this project. This is what I have:

```
      lazy val gridfs = GridFS[BSONSerializationPack.type](db, "resource")
      gridfs.find(BSONDocument("_id" -> BSONObjectID(id))).headOption.map{
        case Some(file) => {
          //this gives me Enumerator[Array[Byte]]. 
          //I'm not using playframework, how to get Future[Array[Byte]] from here?
          gridfs.enumerate(file)
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Play Iteratees is not specific to Play app, but to streaming, like Akka Stream or RxStuff.

You can consume all the chunks of such enumerator using [`Iteratee.consume`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$@consume[E]:play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee.Consume[E]).

```
val sink: Iteratee[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]] = Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()
val allInMem: Future[Array[Byte]] = enumerator |>>> sink
```

> For obvious reason, it's recommanded not to consume big data, but to use appropriate `Iteratee` to process the data in a streaming way.

Comment: I actually have 2 methods, one to get a whole file at once, another to write to a stream. Do you mind to write an example that converts Enumerator to InputStream? Thanks.

Comment: never mind, I think I will keep it as Enumerator[Array[Byte]], and consume it when needed.